# Match DOM text without tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to match text within a string, using JavaScript or jQuery, at any DOM level, which isn't part of an HTML tag.  So, for example, I need to match the word **`foo`** in the following passage exactly 5 times:

```
Foo <p class="foobar" id='foo'>foobar foo<a href="/foo">foo</a> foo.</p>
```

I need to keep the full text intact, with tags, for later use.  This is to wrap each result in a `<span />` tag using find/replace, an effort which currently fails when it incorrectly matches parts of tags and links.

It seems obvious to use jQuery's `.html()` method, but this means I have to dodge those pesky tags.  The necessary regex is getting too complicated for me to handle.  (I also know regex on HTML carries some risk; I'm open to another approach.)

For example, I tried using jQuery's `.text()` method, which lets me manipulate the text as I want using find/replace, but it's seemingly impossible then to update the page source, because you're dealing with the DOM's text node: it won't let me insert those `<span>` tags into the source.

Otherwise, I'm stumped.  Thanks!

Comment: How about `$('*:contains("foo")')`

Comment: match on `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

To target selectors that contain a particular string, use jQuery's `contains` selector. You can then iterate over all such elements with the `each` function.

```
$('*:contains("foo")').each(function() {
    $(this).html("<span class='bold'>" + $(this).text() + "</span>");
});
```

It should be noted that the `contains` selector is case sensitive! We need to modify the jQuery method to allow `Foo` to be found. Add this code to your jQuery file.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Another solution is to use jQuery's `filter` function like so

```
var selection = $("*").filter(function() {
    return /FOO/i.test($(this).text());
});
```

This is probably a better practice because you don't have to modify the original jQuery code. The `test` method takes a regular expression and returns a `Boolean` on whether or not a string contains said expression. The `/i` flag makes the regex case insensitive. It will match the following

- Foo
- foo
- FOO
- fOo

Comment: Will this consider even the foo prior to <p>?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that one. The p selector won't match that. Let me fix this

Comment: Thanks.  Re: your first solution, `$('*:contains("foo")')`, etc.: this will select the ENTIRE body of the tag to wrap.  I need to only wrap a particular match within this string, not the whole string.

Comment: Re: the second solution, `$("*").filter`, etc.: this is the crux of the problem.  Using the HTML text node, you cannot then wrap the found text in `<span>` tags, because you're not dealing with source anymore.  I need a way to carry the modifications back to the source.

Answer (score 1):

To access just the text use the .text() method, so :
(had to escape single quotes)

```
$('<div>Foo <p class="foobar" id=\'foo\'>foobar foo<a href="/foo">foo</a> foo.</p></div>').text()
```

returns: **"Foo foobar foofoo foo."**

Do what you will from there.

Comment: Yes, but once you're only operating on the text node, you are no longer able to wrap the text in <span />, right?